# What kind of Force abilities were affected by Ysalamir?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

So Ysalamiri create Force-empty bubbles, but what exactly is affected by this? Are you not able to use the Force at all or can you just not use Force abilities like Force push, that influence the surroundings? Basically, they take away the Force from a certain space around you if you are close enough, right? So if I wanted to use something like Force speed or some other ability that enhances my physical abilities or tutaminis (just to name give some examples), would I still not be able to use those kinds of abilities, because technically I wouldn't use the Force surrounding me, but the Force inside me, right?

So this leads me to the following question:
**Are Force abilities, that only influence myself and not my surroundings influenced by the Force-empty bubble created by a Ysalamir or not?**

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ysalamir

Comment: It's not canon, but in the _Heir to the Empire_ trilogy Luke feels that his *connection to the force* has been cut when he's inside the influence of the ysalamiri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Force is an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds and penetrates an individual. You have to have a connection to it to use Force powers.

The [Ysalamiri](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ysalamir) create a bubble around them which pushes back the Force, removing the ability to connect to the Force, as a survival mechanism to avoid predators ([Vornskrs](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vornskr)) on their home planet ([Myrkr](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Myrkr/Legends)). **This is now EU** as it is from the [Thrawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrawn_trilogy) trilogy which also predates midichlorians in the prequels.

**The net effect is that a Jedi (or Sith) cannot use the Force when within a bubble**, and powers like Force lightning invoked from outside a bubble cannot harm a target within one.
Another interesting effect is that a clone can be grown at an accelerated rate in a [Spaarti cloning cylinder](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Spaarti_cloning_cylinder) with a Ysalamiri blocking the Force so the clone doesn't suffer from clone madness. This allows clones to be grown in 2-3 weeks vs. the year or longer normally needed to avoid clone madness.

If you read the Thrawn trilogy, a lot of this is covered in more detail.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a good answer, but you could make the sentence about not using the Force at all a bit more obvious, since it directly answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the book New Rebellion,
Luke Skywalker(master jedi) fought Krueller(master sith). Han brought a ysalmari to Pydyr(or Almania, I forget which)-where their duel was taking place. Leia ended up shooting Krueller out of anger, while the ysalamari was close. Both Luke and Krueller felt like they were in deep water. Luke couldn't feel anything, and started laughing at Krueller who was in total shock and had no clue wth was going on. He wondered if Leia would turn now, and deduced no because they couldn't feel the force.
It appears to be a bubble being radiated out based on proximity, as telekinesis started to fail but was ok at first.